# please how do I create this declaration page on latex, the major challenge is inserting the lines though

Tags: pdftex, line

[image: image of the declaration page I intend to create with latex]

please I need assistance in inserting a line for signature/date in the declaration page of a research document using latex! assistance would greatly be appreciated

Comment: A short horizontal rule can be drawn using `\rule{3cm}{0.5pt}`. The placement can be done either widh minipages or a tabular. Apart from that, please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! what you try so far? for lines you can use `\cline` in `tabularx` environment:  `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cXc} & & &\\ \cline{1-1}\cline{3-3} text & & text \end{tabularx}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want it at the bottom of the page. So, something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\leavevmode%
\vfill\noindent
\begin{center}
  \textbf{DECLARATION}
\end{center}
I declare that the work in this dissertation blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah b blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.

\vspace*{4em}\noindent
\hfill%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
  \rule{10em}{0.4pt}\\ ETIM Emmanuel
\end{tabular}%
\hfill%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}
  \rule{10em}{0.4pt}\\ Date
\end{tabular}%
\hfill\strut
\end{document}
```

[image]